# Hibernate mapping xml many-to-many array

Tags: arrays, many-to-many, hibernate-mapping

I am currently working on some legacy code at the moment, so I am not able to change the [database schema](http://i.tinyuploads.com/GW8Plt.png) or domain model.

The java objects look like this:

```
class Person {
  private int prsnId; //get, set
  private int custId; //get, set
  private String name; //get, set
  private String mail; //get, set
  private String status; //get, set
  private String logon; //get, set
  private Contact[] contact; //get, set, add
}

class Contact {
  private int cntcId; //get, set
  private int prorId; //get, set
  private String contactType; //get, set
  private String contactLanguage; //get, set
  private String contactUser; //get, set
}
```

I am trying to create a mapping which will allow me to perform following query, so it returns a list of Persons with their contacts in the contacts-array:

```
List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();
int customerId = /*something*/;
DetachedCriteria subQuery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(PersonOrg.class, "persorg")
.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.property("persorg.prsnId")))
.add(Restrictions.eq("custId", customerId));
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Person.class);
criteria.setFetchMode("Person", FetchMode.JOIN)
    .setFirstResult(0)
    .setMaxResults(20)
    .add(Property.forName("prsnId").in(subQuery));          
personList = criteria.list();
```

with the mapping I have now I get a list of Persons, but their contact-array is filled with null values. And it isn't clear to my why.
My mapping so far is:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="be.bene.cris2.protocol.Person" table="BENE_CUST_PERSON" dynamic-update="true" dynamic-insert="true">
        <id name="prsnId" type="int">
            <column name="PRSN_ID" precision="10" scale="0" />
             <generator class="sequence">
                   <param name="sequence">CUST_PROR_SEQ</param>
            </generator>
        </id>

        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="NAME" length="20" />
        </property> 

        ...

        <array name="contact" table="BENE_CUST_PERSORG" inverse="true" fetch="join">
            <key column="PRSN_ID" not-null="false"/>
            <index column="CUST_ID"/>
            <many-to-many entity-name="be.bene.cris2.protocol.Contact" column="PROR_ID" not-found="ignore"/>
        </array>

        <join table="BENE_CUST_PERSORG">
            <key column="PRSN_ID"/>
            <property name="custId" column="CUST_ID"/>
            <property name="prorId" column="PROR_ID"/>
            <property name="persorgType" type="be.bene.cris2.usertypes.CustomMasterSecundaryTertiaryIndicatorType" column="PERSORG_TYPE"/>
        </join>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

If there is information missing, please ask.

- We use hibernate 3.6.1

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
<join table="BENE_CUST_PERSORG">
  <key column="PRSN_ID"/>
  <property name="custId" column="CUST_ID"/>
  <property name="prorId" column="PROR_ID"/>
  <property name="persorgType" type="be.bene.cris2.usertypes.CustomMasterSecundaryTertiaryIndicatorType" column="PERSORG_TYPE"/>
  <array name="contact" inverse="true">
    <key column="PROR_ID" not-null="false"/>
    <index column="<columninContactTablecontainingArrayIndex>"/> or <index formula="(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() FROM Contacts c WHERE <FK matches> )"/>
    <one-to-many entity-name="be.bene.cris2.protocol.Contact" not-found="ignore"/>
  </array>
</join>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I implement your solution I get following error: 'The content of element type "join" must match "(subselect?,comment?,key,(property|many-to-one|component|dynamic-component|any)*,sql-insert?,sql-update?,sql-delete?)". Person.hbm.xml'  So it seems that the array tag is not valid inside a join tag. We use hibernate 3.6.1, should I use a more recent version?

Comment: sorry i don't know. I tested this with NHibernate where this is valid so i assumed hibernate can do this as well.

Comment: No problem, thanks for taking the time to test it in NHibernate